# How to paste string around predictor variables to create list of model combinations in R?

Tags: r, combinations, apply, paste, mgcv

I have a vector of twelve predictor variables that I want all possible combinations for:

```
#variable vector
d_pred <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K" , "L")

#all possible combinations 
library(combinat)
pred_mat  <- combn(d_pred, 4)
```

Then, I am trying to combine each column in pred_mat (the predictor matrix) into a gam model, so my desired output for the first column (V1) would be:

```
log(Y) ~ s(A,k=4) + s(B, k=4) + s(C, k=4) + s(D, k=4)
```

Where Y is the response variable. Ultimately I would like to have each column into a model list so I can feed the list into a function to calculate the model for each combination:

```
library(mgcv)
data= my_data
allModelsResults <- lapply(allModelsList,
                           function(x) gam(x, data=data))
```

To create the "allModelList" I have tried:

```
allModelsList <- apply(pred_mat, 1, function(x) as.formula(
  paste(c("log(Y) ~ s(", pred_mat[x]), "(k= 4)"
        collapse=" + ")) )
```

But it does not work. I have looked all around but had no luck. Does anyone know how to add the "s(" and "),k=4" around each predictor variable for within combination column (ie. each column in pred_mat)?

Thank you so much!

Comment: From a statistical point of view this is a terrible idea; fit the full model and use `select = TRUE` if you want to do model selection in {mgcv}. Setting `k=4` restricts the fits to things close to a cubic polynomial in each covariate; are you sure you want to be that restrictive?

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```r
allModelsList <- apply(pred_mat, 1, function(x) as.formula(
  paste0("log(Y) ~ ", paste("s(", x, ", k=4)", collapse ="+")) ))
```

This should return

```
head(allModelsList)
#> [[1]]
#> log(Y) ~ s(A, k = 4) + s(B, k = 4) + s(C, k = 4) + s(D, k = 4)
#> <environment: 0x00000230b4c16968>
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> log(Y) ~ s(A, k = 4) + s(B, k = 4) + s(C, k = 4) + s(E, k = 4)
#> <environment: 0x00000230b4c1bcc0>
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> log(Y) ~ s(A, k = 4) + s(B, k = 4) + s(C, k = 4) + s(F, k = 4)
#> <environment: 0x00000230b4d30760>
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> log(Y) ~ s(A, k = 4) + s(B, k = 4) + s(C, k = 4) + s(G, k = 4)
#> <environment: 0x00000230b4d31c38>
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> log(Y) ~ s(A, k = 4) + s(B, k = 4) + s(C, k = 4) + s(H, k = 4)
#> <environment: 0x00000230b4d33110>
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> log(Y) ~ s(A, k = 4) + s(B, k = 4) + s(C, k = 4) + s(I, k = 4)
#> <environment: 0x00000230b4d3a428>
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin Gal! However I am not getting the same output when I run this code on my machine however. It seems to be combining by row rather than by column resulting in "> View(allModelsList)
> head(allModelsList)
[[1]]
log(Y) ~ s(A, k = 4) + s(A, k = 4) + s(A, k = 4) + s(A, k = 4) + 
      s(A, k = 4) + s(A, k = 4) + s(A, k = 4) + s(A, k = 4) + 
    s(A, k = 4) + s(A, k = 4) + s(A, k = 4) + s(A, k = 4) + s(A, 
    k = 4) + s(A, k = 4) + s(A, k = 4) + s(A, k = 4) + s(A, k = 4) + 
+ (etc)". Any ideas why this could be and how to remedy it?

Comment: Nevermind! I figured it out, 1 is for applying by rows and 2 is for applying by column therfore it is ```allModelsList <- apply(pred_mat, 1, function(x) as.formula(
  paste0("log(Y) ~ ", paste("s(", x, ", k=4)", collapse ="+")) ))```.

Comment: Try `pred_mat <- t(pred_mat)` first and then the from above again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `x` itself, use `eval(parse(text = paste0(x)))` in `gam(x, data=data)`, like `gam(eval(parse(text = paste0(x))), data=data)`

Comment: thanks for the reply! Do you mind explaining why though? I used ```allModelsResults <- lapply(allModelsList,
                           function(x) gam(x, data=data))``` and it seemed to work fine. Is there a hidden problem with that I am missng? Thanks!